# React Native Could not read path @babel\core\node_modules\json5\.bin\json5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, json5

I cannot build the project for `android`. When ever I run the `gradlew assembleRelease`, I get the following error:

> Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAsset
>   s' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
>
> Could not read path 'E:\React Native\IRStocks\node_modules\@babel\core\node_mo
>   dules\json5.bin\json5'.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "latest",
    "babel-core": "latest",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.49.0",
    "mobx": "4.3.1",
    "mobx-react": "5.1.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "0.18.0",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.0.18",
    "react-navigation": "^2.17.0",
    "searchable-flatlist": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
```

BTW:

```
Environment:
  OS: Windows 8.1
  Node: 8.11.2
  Yarn: 1.12.1
  npm: 6.1.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Version  2.3.0.0 AI-162.3871768

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Any idea?

Comment: This might be related to having multiple versions of babel installed

Comment: I removed all of them except but the problem is still there...

Comment: If you delete `node_modules` and reinstall, does the error persist?

Comment: @loganfsmyth - yes! i delete that and run `yarn` but it's still  have problem!

Comment: I once had a somewhat similar problem when I first tested out `RN@0.57.3`. Try downloading this package: https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade and then run the `babel-upgrade --write` command at the root of your project. Hope it helps.

Comment: Same issue here. When you go to 'E:\React Native\IRStocks\node_modules\@babel\core\node_mo dules\json5.bin' is json5 a <JUNCTION>?

Comment: yes! thats a shortcut :|

Comment: I've solved this for my setup!

The problem is that webpack (I think) is not respecting the <JUNCTION> symlinks (I don't actually think they should be JUNCTIONs), so I wrote a console app - gist here: https://gist.github.com/christianchown/62d929cf196cd8782635288bfeba6069 - that scans node_modules and replace junctions with real files.

Message me if you'd like .exe rather than the source code in that gist

Comment: Here's that gist as a repo: https://github.com/christianchown/nojunction - there's an .exe in there

Comment: Thanks! Would you please add `.exe` in the repo?

Comment: It's there already, `nojunction.exe` here: https://github.com/christianchown/nojunction/tree/master/bin/Debug

Comment: Thanks! I used `npm install` instead of `yarn` and now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was because of `Yarn: 1.12.1` and it's solved when I upgraded to `1.12.3`.

Comment: I'm tired to upgrade yarn to 1.12.3 but it's not upgraded idk why? what's the command you use to upgrade?

Comment: I've uninstalled them from the control panel in Win and when i check the -v i see 1.16.0 so, when i  run  gradlew assembleRelease i Got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239244/cant-generating-the-release-apk-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this. Seems to be a problem with newer Yarn versions on Windows.

I am using yarn version 1.12.1 and I got the same problem.

I have downgraded yarn version to 1.10.1 then it works!

Step by step:

1. Uninstall yarn 1.12.1
2. Install yarn 1.10.1
3. Go to project folder and execute `yarn install`
4. Build my project and the error is gone

Comment: can you update your answer with command line to every single step?