# Can't Generating the release APK - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I want to Generate an APK, I follow these steps [In Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) but still have A Build Failed

```
1. cd android

2. gradlew clean "build Successful"

3. gradlew assembleRelease "BUILD FAILED" with this
```

> Could not read path '\node_modules@babel\parser.bin\parser'.

Here is package.json File

#### Package.Json

```
{
  "name": "DemoApp",
  "version": "1.12.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/distance": "^6.0.1",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.1.4",
    "@turf/invariant": "^6.1.2",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.2.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.3.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/parser": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-devtools": "^3.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and solved by downgrading yarn version to 1.10.1, then it works. May it work for you as well.

```
Uninstall yarn 1.12.3
Install yarn 1.10.1
Go to project folder and execute yarn install
Build my project and the error is gone
```

Comment: I'm already downgrading yarn to 1.10.1 but I got new error `Could not read script 'node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' as it does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `node_module` folder and then run `npm install`.